# Positioning text within a width:100% (liquid?) header and footer elements

Tags: html, css, text, positioning

Some background: Nearly every site I build is based on using a center container div where everything you see on the screen is contained within, for example, a 1000px wide container. Nothing to the left or right and no top or bottom bars that extend off to the left or right sides of the screen. Now it's time to build a site with top and bottom bars that expand out past the 1000px container div. Got that part, right down to the bars themselves.

The Problem: I want to position text (links to be exact) within the top and bottom bars, not dissimilar to how SO looks here. This is where I'm getting messed up because I want to do this without absolute positioning, or JS or jQ or via plugin. When I add a div to contain the text within, say, the top bar, it sits happily to the left of the top bar, not where I want it. I have searched, researched and made small attempts to figure this out but to no avail.

THEREFORE: I built a sample site which includes an image if how I would like things to look. The site is bare minimum on HTML and CSS to (hopefully) make things clear, and can be found [HERE](http://xoverr.net/test/index.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
#top_content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

This will make any text within `<div id="top_content">here</div>` align with your main 1000px container while `<div id="topbar">` still expands to 100% of the browser width.

Do the same for your footer, giving it an inner div and targeting it with CSS to give it auto left/right margins and 1000px width so it centers under the main #content container.

Comment: I believe I tried that and the result was a div placed directly below the top bar where I wanted it inside the top bar as shown on the test site. I'll give it another whirl now.

Comment: Well...You were 100% right, thank you! I could have sworn I tried that earlier today to no avail. I must have been foggy in the brain, so thank you for shedding the light I needed to see the solution.

Comment: Your welcome! Btw, it might be better to change the width from 1000px to 700px (matching #content width) instead of adding the right margin on the p.top class.

Comment: Agreed. Though there are some other pages using this overall template that will have a wider container, but sound advice all the same.